# ServerSocket vs Socket -- closing the socket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

Both [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close%28%29) and [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%29) have the method `close()` to close the socket.

What is the difference between the two?

Suppose, on the server side,

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();  
...
```

In this case, how is

```
socket.close();
```

different from

```
serverSocket.close();
```

if any?

TIA.

Comment: Do you have Knowledge of difference between Socket and Server Socket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ServerSocket sets up a listener from which you can accept any number of Socket connections.  Closing a Socket closes that one connection; closing the ServerSocket means the listener is closed and can no longer accept connections to that port.

Comment: That was my understanding till i read the Java specs on the two close() methods. they sound the same. haven`t tried myself on code.

Answer (score -1):

java.net.ServerSocket

This class implements server sockets. A server socket waits for requests to come in over the network. It performs some operation based on that request, and then possibly returns a result to the requester.

java.net.Socket

This class implements client sockets (also called just "sockets"). A socket is an endpoint for communication between two machines.

In simple words, socket is from client side and serversocket is from server side

Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Comment: The question was more on how Socket's close() is different from ServerSocket's close() and not the difference between  Socket and ServerSocket!

Comment: `Socket` is used at both sides. You haven't answered the question.